# Turn RDD in Spark with key/[value] pairs into key/value pairs for each value in the values list

Tags: java, apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd

I'm doing transformations on an RDD derived from an Avro Schema.  My Avro class looks something like this:

```
public class myAvroSchema {
    public String myKey;
    public Collection<Value> myValues;
    public Object someOtherObject;
}
```

The current transformation I'm performing on the data set is as follows:

```
JavaRDD<myAvroSchema> myResult = AvroRDD.create(mySparkContext);
myResult.filter(aResult -> !aResult.getmyValues().isEmpty())
    .mapToPair(aResult -> Tuple.of(aResult.getKey(), aResult.getMyValues());
```

This gives me a `JavaRDD<String, Collection<Value>>`, but what I really want is to return back `JavaRDD<String, Value>`.

I can't figure out how to take my `<Key>,Collection<Value>` pair and flatten out the values so that there are now multiple rows with the same key, but a different value for each row.

For example, say my result looks something like this:

```
<KeyA, [Value1, Value2]>
<KeyB, [Value3, Value4]>
```

I would like to transform it to look like this:

```
<KeyA, Value1>
<KeyA, Value2>
<KeyB, Value3>
<KeyB, Value4>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [flatMapValues](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html#flatMapValues(org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function))

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Collection<Value>> immediateResult = myResult.filter(aResult -> !aResult.getmyValues().isEmpty())
.mapToPair(aResult -> Tuple.of(aResult.getKey(), aResult.getMyValues());
JavaPairRDD<String, Collection<Value>> result = immediateResult.flatMapValues((Collection<Value> x) -> x)
```

*Code was written without possibility to check; it's only general idea to use flatMapValues with identity function. If there is some typo - sorry, I have no possibility to check it now*